# Conditionally sort WPF CollectionViewSource

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to do a conditional sorting for WPF collection view source?

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCVS" Source="{Binding MyData}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
      <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="MyProperty1" Direction="Ascending" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

I want to sort on MyProperty1 under some condition and MyProperty2 under some other condition. I may be able to do it in code behind. But I would prefer do it Xaml itself if it is possible.

Something like if "MySortCondition" is true then sort by MyProperty1 if not sort by MyProperty2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you write a converter to change your `MySortCondition` into the appropriate `SortDescription` object (probably have to make the `SortDescriptionCollection` yourself in the converter...)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly `SortDescriptions` are not very customizable as tey are `stucts` and cant be derived to add this logic, so code behind will be your best option.

```
   var cvs = FindResource("MyCVS") as CollectionViewSource;
   cvs.SortDescriptions.Clear();
   if (condition)
   {
      cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Property1", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
   }
   else 
   {
      cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Property2", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
   }
```

---

Or... If both properties are of the same type the simple way would be to create a Sort property in your class and use that in the `SortDescription`

Example:

```
public int SortProperty
{
   get
   {
       if (condition)
       {
          return Property1;
       }
       return Property2;
   }
}
```

---

But in most cases its easier to sort the underlying collection first using Linq

```
public List<Type> MyData
{
    get
    {
        return _data.OrderBy(x => .........
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The type will be different for them string, int, enum etc. So that is out. I will have resort to the code behind solution I guess.